# Is it always necessary to query a database via thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, rest

Is it always necessary to query a database via thread in a normal rest api build using java/kotlin and spring boot.
Eg :-

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<MyEntity> findEntityByIdAsync(Long id) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(myRepository.findById(id).orElse(null));
    }
}
```

or is it ok to simply query without using threads explicitly :-

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    
    public MyEntity findEntityByIdAsync(Long id) {
        return myRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in most situations, you don't need to use a thread to query databases in most web applications like use send a request and he wait for the response. because the request should be response in a short time. if the time consuming is to long, that is a design problem or performance problem, and we need to optimize the databases.

If you always use a new thread to query data from database, that means every request the server will use double thread, that is a waste for the whole server.

hope to help you